# formula contar si google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

En una hoja de cálculo estoy realizando un conteo de prendas que cuando aparece la fecha cuente todas las  fechas de ese día. Mi problema es que no se que estoy formulando mal que me cuenta las fechas pero luego la del día siguiente la cuenta y la de arriba suma todas las fechas, la solución que tengo por ahora es que cree una columna y con número y le coloque por ejemplo fecha 14/12/2021 a su lado coloque 1

Si es 15/12/2021 a su lado coloque 2 y así el contar si la fórmula si me cuenta pero no es útil que yo coloque los número manuales. para la fecha si tengo un script que me genera la fecha automática cada vez que ingresa un código en la hoja.

```js
function tiempoAutomatico() {
  var archivo =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = archivo.getSheetByName("CODIGOS");
  var activa = ss.getActiveCell();
  var valor =activa.getValue();
  var filaActiva = activa.getRow();
  var colActiva =activa.getColumn();

  if(filaActiva>=2 && colActiva==8 && archivo.getActiveSheet().getName()=="CODIGOS"){
    if(activa.offset(0,1).getValue()){  
    
    }else{
    activa.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}


function tiempoAutomatico1() {
  var archivo =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = archivo.getSheetByName("linea1");
  var activa = ss.getActiveCell();
  var valor =activa.getValue();
  var filaActiva = activa.getRow();
  var colActiva =activa.getColumn();

  if(filaActiva>=3 && colActiva==8 && archivo.getActiveSheet().getName()=="linea1"){
    if(activa.offset(0,1).getValue()){  
    
    }else{
    activa.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}


function tiempoAutomatico2() {
  var archivo =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = archivo.getSheetByName("linea2");
  var activa = ss.getActiveCell();
  var valor =activa.getValue();
  var filaActiva = activa.getRow();
  var colActiva =activa.getColumn();

  if(filaActiva>=3 && colActiva==8 && archivo.getActiveSheet().getName()=="linea2"){
    if(activa.offset(0,1).getValue()){  
    
    }else{
    activa.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}

function tiempoAutomatico3() {
  var archivo =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = archivo.getSheetByName("linea3");
  var activa = ss.getActiveCell();
  var valor =activa.getValue();
  var filaActiva = activa.getRow();
  var colActiva =activa.getColumn();

  if(filaActiva>=3 && colActiva==8 && archivo.getActiveSheet().getName()=="linea3"){
    if(activa.offset(0,1).getValue()){  
    
    }else{
    activa.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}

function tiempoAutomatico4() {
  var archivo =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = archivo.getSheetByName("linea4");
  var activa = ss.getActiveCell();
  var valor =activa.getValue();
  var filaActiva = activa.getRow();
  var colActiva =activa.getColumn();

  if(filaActiva>=3 && colActiva==8 && archivo.getActiveSheet().getName()=="linea4"){
    if(activa.offset(0,1).getValue()){  
    
    }else{
    activa.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}


function onEdit(){
tiempoAutomatico()
tiempoAutomatico1()
tiempoAutomatico2()
tiempoAutomatico3()
tiempoAutomatico4()
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradeceria su apoyo en como podria solucionar este problema

```
=CONTAR.SI(J:J,L3)
```

como puede ver yo con el script hago que aparezca la fecha y la hora. cuando usan el lector de barras. mi problema viene que cuando intento usar la formula contar.si para que cuente esa fecha genera por mi script no lo hace de manera correcta pero si detallan  la foto al lado de la fecha coloque unos numero para hacer el conto y si realiza el conteo adecuadamente. no se si existe algun modo de modificar mi scripts para que haga el conteo de las fechas ya eso si lo desconozco.

Comment: Aparentemente el código no tiene que ver de forma directa con el problema que con el cual estás solicitando ayuda, por otro lado no se incluyen las fórmulas que estás usando. Me parece que debes quitar el código e indicar las fórmulas además de incluir datos de ejemplo y el resultado esperado en forma de texto.

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba que en ambas columnas las celdas tengan formato de Fecha. Una vez hecho esto solamente tienes que añadir la primera fecha que desees y en la celda inferior añadir +1 al valor que tienes. Posteriormente arrastras la fórmula hasta la fecha que desees.
Después en la columna M, como ves en la imagen, ya puedes añadir la fórmula

```
=CONTAR.SI(J:J,L3)
```

[image: Captura de pantalla de Google Spreadsheets]

[image: Captura de pantalla de Google Spreadsheets]

Comment: no me funciono eso rubén, pero si logre solucionar al intentar lo que me comentaste porque vi que mi script me crean la hora y fecha. asi que use otra formula

=ARRAYFORMULA(IZQUIERDA(I3:I, LARGO(I4)-0)) para que no muestre la hora en otra casilla y solo la fecha y a partir de esa casilla hacer el conteo. muchas gracias por el apoyo. rubén.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que tu script mande la fecha ya formateada en vez de estarla formateado en una celda nueva de excel. En vez de usar simplemente `New Date()` puedes usar una función como esta:

```
function fecha() {
  var opciones = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
  var fecha = new Date()
    .toLocaleDateString('es', opciones)
    .replace(/ /g, '-')
    .replace('.', '')
    .replace(/-([a-z])/, function (x) { return '-' + x[1].toUpperCase() });
  return fecha;
}
```

Puedes encontrar más información para formatear fechas [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)